# Why isn't this DE in "normal form"?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm working through Edward & Penney's Elementary DEs book, and on page 7 it says that all the equations in the book will stick to DEs that are in normal form, as in

$y^{n}=G(x,y,y',y'',...,y^{n-1})$

The counter example given is

$(y')^2+y^2=0$

and it says this is in implicit form.  But if I rearrange, I have

$y'=(-y^2)^\frac{1}{2}$

I have the highest order of the function defined in terms of either $x$ or lower orders of $y$.  Isn't this in normal form?  Or is it because this isn't an ODE?

Comment: Many equations that are not in normal form can be converted to one in normal form (as your example).  So E&P are saying they assume such conversions have already been done, and then will only discuss the resulting normal form equation.

Comment: And, technically, from your original equation you actually get TWO normal form equations: one that you wrote, and one with the negative of the square-root.

Comment: @GEdgar Oh ok.  I understand. I thought there was more to it.  Thanks.